# Unable to install python3-venv

Tags: apt, python, python3

I am trying to install `python3-venv` ubuntu package but I have this error:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-venv : Depends: python3.5-venv (>= 3.5.1-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So I tried install `python3.5-venv` but without any success:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-venv

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.5-venv : Depends: python3.5 (= 3.5.1-10) but 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried use `conda` and downgrade my python version from 3.5.2 to 3.5.1 but error is still occurs.

```
conda install python=3.5.1
```

My Ubuntu version => **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS 64-bit**

I also tried `sudo apt install -f` but this didn't solve my problem.

Where can be a problem?

Comment: Are you doing some sort of cross-compiling? What's the output of `apt-cache policy python3.5-venv`?

Comment: Here is the output. I need setup virtual enviroment for my project. `python3.5-venv:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.5.1-10
  Version table:
     3.5.1-10 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally found solution. I have broken source.list. I regenerate new one here:

https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

And replace at `/etc/apt/`

Answer (score -1):

`venv` is in the standard modules since Python 3.3 and means you don't have to install it separately.

```
python3 -m venv my_venv
```

Comment: For the record, on at least Ubuntu 16.04 and all versions of Debian as far as I know, you do have to install it separately: they package pieces that it depends on in a default invocation (specifically the `ensurepip` module) in an external package that isn't installed in by default with the rest of Python 3.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04, this is not the case. `venv` is not available by default.