# unable to install venv on python3.8

Tags: python

I am trying to install python3-venv and get below error. I have looked at similar threads, esp this one: [Unable to install python3-venv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/949393/unable-to-install-python3-venv)

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, using it through Windows 10 (WSL).

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.8-venv : Depends: python3.8 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu1) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: thanks karel but didn't help, i have tried all the options.

Comment: i have even tried to install an older version (the bionic one) which had python 3.6 and it fails as well for exact same thing

Comment: There is a version mismatch. Seems APT is trying to install python3.8-venv version 3.8.2-1ubuntu1 which is in focal/universe which depends on  Python 3.8.2-1ubuntu1. Consider either disabling `focal-updates/main` and `focal-security/main` or enable `focal-updates/universe` or `focal-security/universe` to get  python3.8-venv 3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2.